# Rankings plummeted when I changed H1 tags to match the title, can I recover my rankings by reversing the changes?

Tags: title, heading, h1

I recently changed a lot (most?) of H1 tags on my site to match the page title. Then my rankings plummeted.

I'm now on page 5.

I then learned that matching title and H1 tags may be considered over-optimization by Google.

So I changed all the titles again.

Have I just ruined my website forever or will it eventually recover from this?

Comment: This site uses the H1, a tag, and the brand name as the title, so the title and the h1 tags mostly match on every question page.  I'm not sure that an over optimization penalty is what is what is wrong with your site.

Comment: I saw it in a warning in the SEMRush report. Here's what it says about it: "It is a bad idea to duplicate your title tag content in your first-level header. If your page's <title> and <h1> tags match, the latter may appear over-optimized to search engines. Also, using the same content in titles and headers means a lost opportunity to incorporate other relevant keywords for your page."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Your `h1` is likely not the culprit, but let's find out

First of all, I'd wait about 2 weeks before doing anything. Google *just* finished rolling out their [November spam update](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-november-2021-spam-update-32365.html). SERPs are a bit volatile at the moment. Sit tight until the dust settles.

Below is ***all*** you need to think about when writing title tags and `h1`'s. Do this and your meta data should be just fine.

1. Choose a primary and secondary (variant) keyword for a page. Your secondary keyword should be another way people refer to the primary one.
2. Use your primary keyword *somewhere* in the title tag
3. Use your variant in your H1 tag
4. Write great content and publish it. Then wait 3 months, see how it's doing, and *then* think about tinkering with things.

Focus on writing in a captivating way that intrigues people. Use natural language. Also don't forget about your meta description. Go through this process once and if you get your rankings back, leave em alone!

If you don't then...

### You *can* recover, but you need to find the problem first.

Like I said before, I would be surprised if your `h1` is the cause here, but I hope I'm wrong. We just wouldn't normally expect rankings to "plummet" like that because Google doesn't give the `h1` *that* much weight. Heck, I've ranked pages in the top 10 without having one! In my experience a significant drop like that is almost always due to one of the following:

1. Penalty after a Google algorithm update
2. An unrealized mistake caused a crawling/indexing issue

At this point you'd want to audit your site, dot your i's and cross your t's, and don't make any drastic changes until you know what's actually going on. Probably half the issues I find in audits are the result of a client trying to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been trying to get this site to rank for over 10 years with no joy. It kept falling towards the bottom of page 2 where it stayed for years - and recently (within the last month) it plummeted to the bottom of page 5. And getting people to link to me - even though the software is free - is like pulling teeth.

Comment: @Richard I just looked at the site briefly. Seems like an awesome tool. Currently your blog is only 6 pages - one page for each year. These need to all be unique posts! Go through the steps I outlined in my answer for each. When it comes to writing new content - some long form stuff could do you good. Guides, How-to searches, web development news/opinion. Here are some resources I think you'll find useful: https://mailchimp.com/resources/best-free-keyword-research-tools/. I _hate_ this buzzword, but you have a lot of "low hanging fruit".

Comment: The most important thing you can do is get other people to start writing about and linking to your site.

Comment: @barbecue That's easier said than done - for some reason my software doesn't seem to have a great reputation.

Comment: @Mike  I think it's awesome too! Trying to get others to see that too is proving to be rather tricky.

Comment: @Richard Personally, I like the basic design you have, I think most developers and engineers probably see the tool don't think twice. However, it could be the case that it isn't resonating with younger audiences or product managers/designers (that don't code) tasked with finding a solution for their site/product. If you wind up moving to wordpress or something that would handle the content organization for you _and_ you could also easily test a more edgy/modern pre-designed theme.

Comment: It's a shame that the actual usefulness of a product plays less of a role in its success than the marketing. Unfortunately, it's really hard to be noticed without playing the soul-sucking games of flavor-of-the-month UI and SEO shenanigans.

Comment: @barbecue I wish I could upvote your comment more than once!

Comment: @Mike I'm really not a design monkey! :-) The RGraph site is, I think, an example of the best that I can do design-wise. To get it any nicer I think I'd need to buy a design from one of those template websites. TBH, other sites in the niche don't have whizz-bang designs either IMO, eg www.chartjs.org.

Comment: @barbecue Yeah I agree it sucks

Comment: @Richard I only mentioned the design as a possibility, your tool is great I've been playing with it. I think that if you focus on content, work on the title tags and meta data, and organize your blog as individual pages you'll see a lot of improvement.

Comment: @Richard One other suggestion I have is for you to ramp up your participation on Github. You've got a lot of content on your site currently that could be linked from your Github pages, and vice versa. And getting some collaborators might help as well.

Comment: Do you mean linked from the GitHub project front page? (ie here: https://github.com/heyesr/rgraph ) There are some links to some demos on that page, as well as some links to various pages on the website.

Comment: @Richard I think barbecue is suggesting that you look at opportunities to improve your sites linking (in this case pointing any links _to_ your site from other properties that you own, such as your Github.

Comment: Update: I think that I've reversed the huge drop by changing titles & H1 tags so that they're no longer identical. In a lot of cases, they're very different. Now I'm seeing my site at position 25/26. Still not good, but way better than page 5!